Alien Invasion Эрик Мэтиз Python Crash Course. Игра не отвечает
Python. Написал код с книги. Никаких ошибок не выдает, просто само приложение не отвечает и все. Пробовал с разных ПК не помогло. Выводится должен было изображение корабля и серый фон без движений.
alien_invasion.py
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
    
    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game

settings.py
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

ship.py

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/BOSS/alien_invasion/images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

